# How to not generate a title page in pandoc markdown

Tags: titles, templates, pandoc

I don't want to generate a title page. My uni gave me a title page. I could merge it with the pandoc PDF afterwards.

How do I make the default title page disappear?

I tried the following:

Get the current template
`pandoc -D markdown > md.template`

The new template file contains:

```
$if(titleblock)$
$titleblock$

$endif$
$for(header-includes)$
$header-includes$

$endfor$
$for(include-before)$
$include-before$

$endfor$
$if(toc)$
$table-of-contents$

$endif$
$body$
$for(include-after)$

$include-after$
$endfor$
```

Now I deleted this part to not have a title page:

```
$if(titleblock)$
$titleblock$

$endif$
```

Then I run `pandoc --template md.template -V breakurl -V hyphens=URL --pdf-engine=xelatex -o out.pdf in.md` and get this error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \hypertarget
```

What am I doing wrong? Isn't it supposed to work like this? Is there an easier method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to get the template in latex format with `pandoc -D latex > latex.template`.

Then I removed the lines:

```
$if(has-frontmatter)$
\frontmatter
$endif$
$if(title)$
$if(beamer)$
\frame{\titlepage}
$else$
\maketitle
$endif$
$if(abstract)$
\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$
$endif$
```

To use the template I did `pandoc --template latex.template -V breakurl -V hyphens=URL --pdf-engine=xelatex -o out.pdf in.md`.